# Ordering and concatenating two lists of different types

Tags: c#, linq

I have two very similar tables in my database (tblCar and tblPlane).
They have the same columns, only tblCar's start with car_, and tblPlane's start with pl_.
Ie car_id, pl_id etc.

I get the rows from the tables and concatenate them:

```
var cars = (from x in db.tblCar select x).ToList();
var planes = (from x in db.tblPlane select x).ToList();
var result = cars.Cast<object>().Concat(planes.Cast<object>());
```

And it works fine.

But, both tables have a column for date of update: cat_update and pl_update. Its type is DateTime and I need to order the result list by this column, newest first.

How to make the ordering when the properties have different names?

Comment: Maybe it's not the most elegant solution but you could iterate along your result and insert each item in a SortedList class using the DateTime field as a key (using a conditional clause based on typeOf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var orderedResult = cars.Cast<object>().Concat(planes.Cast<object>())
    .OrderBy(o => o is Car? ((Car)o).car_date : ((Plane)o).pl_date);
```

But this isn't very safe. If your tables have the same columns, why can't all the values be in the same column, with a bit field telling you if it is a car or a plane?

Comment: @Srcee since you're casting them to objects you're opening yourself up to runtime errors instead of compiler errors if you make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a parent type for Car and Plane, something like a Vehicle class that both can be cast to? One of the fields on your vehicle class will be _date. So the code would look like this:

```
var orderedResults = cars.Cast<Vehicle>().Concat(planes.Cast<Vehicle>())
       .OrderBy(v => v._date);
```

This way you retain compile time type saftey & have a more logical type hierarchy since all of the columns are the same in both tables you shouldn't have any difficulty representing them as Vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
private class VehicleHolder
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set;}
    public object Vehicle { get;set; }
}

//...

var cars = (from x in db.tblCar 
            select new VehicleHolder() { Date = x.car_date, Vehicle = x }).ToList();
var planes = (from x in db.tblPlane 
              select new VehicleHolder() { Date = x.pl_date, Vehicle = x }).ToList();

var result = cars.Concat(planes).OrderBy(v => v.Date).Select(v => v.Vehicle);
```

But I agree with Chris: a common parent type would be much cleaner.